# Alternative xUnit GUI runner

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

xUnit offers so many appealing features comparing to NUnit but its GUI runner is so poor that it's pain to use it: no tree visualization, theory tests are represented by a single list entry, no remembering last test run, etc. For long time I hoped 2.0 will solve it but it's still in alpha :( I'm on VS 2010 so cannot try new test explorer of VS 2012 and looking for alternatives. So what do you use to run xUnit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to 2012/2013/2015. Fight if necessary. Its Just so much faster and the xUnit runner is perfect (come quibbles on UX but bulletproof). The CodeRush runner support is getting there but put the money towards a VS update.

Also [have a look on the forum - they're ruling out a 2.0 GUI runner as part of the core offering](https://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/459481).

Bottom line is GUI users should and do stop using the GUI if they use VS and try the plugin.

Comment: I'd just like to add that at this time of writing, running xUnit tests in Visual Studio 2017 via the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package can be downright torturous. If you only have a few tests, you might not notice anything wrong. But once your tests number in the hundred, you're going to wait forever until xUnit finishes discovering tests, or the test runner cache gets corrupted and you need to go manually delete it and restart VS. Makes me wish I could go back to NUnit.

Comment: Aside from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103781/why-is-the-visual-studio-2015-2017-test-runner-not-discovering-my-xunit-v2-tests/44520498#44520498 I have to say I find xUnit 2 bullet proof and have no major perf issues in a large codebase with lots of unit and lots of acceptance tests which run in parallel. You're right that it's not painfree, but I somehow doubt that NUnit is as painfree as advertised either...

Answer (score 1):

I use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to run my unit tests. It has [a plugin that allows it to run xUnit tests](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/01/resharper-plugins-for-unit-testing-mspec-xunitnet-and-silverlight/) as well.

The only problem with ReSharper is that it is a commercial product, but it is well worth the money!

Answer (score 1):

With VS2010 - You can try this but there are limitations as mentioned in my comments

http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/5648

> *Few limitations with this extension, but it covers the immediate
>   needs. I personally like it.  xUnit devs use third party runners such
>   as TestDriven.NET / R# to run tests within VS. But if xUnit has an
>   integrated VS2010 runner, then lot of developers will start using
>   xUnit. Which also mean better Unit Tests.*

Answer (score 1):

We use Gallio Icarus. It has a tree view and you can select the test report format. If you are still using VS2010 then it will work for you.

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work with the latest VS2015 framework. That’s why I’m on this post looking for alternatives