# VS2017 - Test runner not picking up Xunit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I went to bed last night with all the tests showing up, reloaded the project today and the VS test runner isn't picking anything up no matter what I try.

I had a similar issue yesterday when I loaded up the project, but resolved it by adding a reference to Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions - as suggested in this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103781/why-is-the-visual-studio-2015-2017-test-runner-not-discovering-my-xunit-v2-tests). But it's now doing the same thing even with the reference. I've also now tried almost all the answers in the post to no avail.

I've compared to a basic console project that works and the references are identical apart from the main project being included:

[image]

I've added this test and nothing shows.

```
using Xunit;

namespace LearnOnlineAppTests
{
    public class BaseTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void DummyTest()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Also been through this: [Xunit documentation](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-desktop.html#run-tests-visualstudio)

Using VS2017 Professional without ReSharper.

Answer (score 3):

Missed an incredibly important step, and one that was mentioned in multiple places.

Xunit.runner.visualstudio was not included in the project.